# Uninitialized constant NameError in Rspec

Tags: ruby, module, rspec

When I run rails c, I can call the following class and the method works:

```
 test = SlackService::BoardGameNotifier
 test.create_alert("test")
  >>method works
```

I'm trying to set this up in rspec like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'slack-notifier'

RSpec.describe SlackService::BoardGameNotifier do
 describe '#notify' do
    @notifier = SlackService::BoardGameNotifier

    it 'pings Slack' do
      error = nil
      message = "test"
      expect(notifier).to receive(:ping).with(message)
      notifier.send_message()
    end
  end
end
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
  NameError:
  uninitialized constant SlackService
```

Does this have to do with how I set up the module?

My current setup:

slack_service/board_game_notifier.rb

```
module SlackService
    class BoardGameNotifier < BaseNotifier
      WEBHOOK_URL =   Rails.configuration.x.slack.url
      DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
        channel: "board-games-channel",
        text: "board games alert",
        username: "bot",
      }

      def create_alert(message)
       message #testing
      end
    end
  end
```

slack_service/base_notifier.rb

```
module SlackService
    class BaseNotifier
      include Singleton

      def initialize
        webhook_url = self.class::WEBHOOK_URL
        options = self.class::DEFAULT_OPTIONS

        @notifier = Slack::Notifier.new(webhook_url, options)
      end

      def self.send_message
        message = instance.create_alert("test")
        instance.notify(message)
      end

      def notify(message)
        @notifier.post blocks: message
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your spec_helper.rb

```rb
# spec_helper.rb

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path("../config/environment", __dir__)
```

When running RSpec, Rails doesn't automatically boot up, and therefore doesn't automatically load all the libraries.

Also, I'd suggest creating a `.rspec` in your app's root folder with the following lines so that spec_helper is automatically loaded for all your RSpec tests:

```sh
# .rspec
--format documentation
--color
--require spec_helper
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [described_class](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/metadata/described-class) from Rspec

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'slack-notifier'

RSpec.describe ::SlackService::BoardGameNotifier do
 describe '#notify' do
    it 'pings Slack' do
      error = nil
      message = "test"
      expect(described_class).to receive(:ping).with(message)
      notifier.send_message()
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is the folder structure of your spec file the same as the original one ?